# Adding brick volume to gluster fails

Tags: linux, fdisk, parted, volume, glusterfs

I created a 2TB volume to increase space on home directory.

I created the partition:

```
$ parted /dev/xvdb mklabel gpt
$ parted -s /dev/xvdb mkpart primary ext4 1 100%
```

Formatted the partition:

```
$ mkfs.ext4 -I 512 /dev/xvdb1
```

Added the entry to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/xvdb /export/home/brick3 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Created the mountpoint:

```
$ mkdir -p /export/home/brick3
$ chmod 0755 /export/home/brick3
```

Mounted the partition:

```
$ mount /export/home/brick3
$ mkdir /export/home/brick3/home
$ chmod 0775 /export/home/brick3/home
```

once I tried to add the new brick to volume thats where I get an error.

```
$ gluster volume add-brick home <hostname>:/export/home/brick3/home
volume add-brick: failed Incorrect number of bricks supplied 1 with count 2
```

Comment: What's the output of the `home` volume look like? `gluster volume info`?

Comment: /dev/xvdca1       992G   843G   99G   90% /export/home/brick1                                            /dev/xvdcn1       992G   82G     859G  9%  /export/home/brick2                                    /dev/xvdcp1       1.8T     68M     1.8T    1%  /export/home/brick3

Comment: Please add this to your Q.

Comment: I am adding all three after gluster volume add-brick... ?

Comment: You need to add the number of replicas to that

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `replica $COUNT`. This is a known issue when you have replicas enabled:

> Current design constraints in replicate module doesn't allow for us to add individual bricks into an existing topology.

#### Scenario

You tried something like this:

```
$ gluster vol add-brick test-volume-replicated3 \
     host:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3

volume add-brick: failed: Incorrect number of bricks supplied 1 with count 2
```

Your scenario is likely one where you have a number of replicas configured for your gluster volume because it was built like this originally:

```
$ gluster vol create test-volume-replicated3 replica 3 \
    host1:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3 \
    host2:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3 \
    host3:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3
volume create: test-volume-replicated3: success: please start the volume to access data
```

And currently its topology is now like this:

```
$ gluster vol info test-volume-replicated3

Volume Name: test-volume-replicated3
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 10b3d0e2-14a2-4ec3-a98c-9a3307f3fd8f
Status: Created
Number of Bricks: 1 x 3 = 3
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: host1:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3
Brick2: host2:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3
Brick3: host3:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3
```

So to get your command to run you have to tell gluster your replica count when adding another brick:

```
$ gluster vol add-brick test-volume-replicated3 replica 3 \
   host:/rhss/bricks/brick1/test-volume-replicated3 \
   host:/rhss/bricks/brick2/test-volume-replicated3 \
   host:/rhss/bricks/brick3/test-volume-replicated3
```

#### References

- [How to add a new brick to an existing replicated volume?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/647813)